# Domain integration with Active Directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain, subdomain, microsoft

Am new to Microsoft Active directory and tried referring the guides for one of the activity. But still not clear how we can achieve it. Scenario goes as below..

Our company has an Active Directory environment with Root Domain as abc.com and then Child Domains as UK.abc.com, US.abc.com and UAE.abc.com

Now our company plans to take over another company say xyz.com

xyz.com user should access resources of abc.com domains (file servers, printers etc.) in each other’s domains.

I have added it in Root domain Trust with Two way direction. Do I need to specify any special permissions to the users for accessing two way ?

Comment: If there are really two companies merging then someone who has experience with Active Directory should be leading the process of integrating the two forests.

Comment: Yes Todd, lead is out of town and I should lead this now.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add users in AD from one domain another domain either to computers/groups/AD,then you need to use AGDULP method. Also, add the DNS suffix in the clients NIC for faster domain location.
-Add the User Accounts to Global Groups> Global Groups to Universal Group> Universal Groups to Domain Local Groups > Domain Local Groups to the group you want to assign the permission. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742592.aspx

Accessing resources across forests
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772808%28WS.10%29.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply Johnyd, I do not want to import the users into my domain. I want to allow xyz.com domain users to access our devices and in same, abc.com domain users also should get access to the files of xyz.com.